# Executing Page Page Load from Popup

Tags: asp.net, javascript

is it possible to trigger Parent's page load event from a popup.When i use javascript function window.parent.document.form.submit,this creates a postback.I want a function which creates "reload" for page because some of my functions work in the "if not postback" statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

window.opener.location=window.opener.location should do the trick for you if memory serves.